# Connecting to a Docker container using domain name from the same physical location

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I have a situation where `node-container` can reach `mongo-container` if it uses `mongo-container`'s name such that Docker translates it to its internal IP (which I think is how it works). They are running at the same Docker host.

However, if developing locally (not on the Docker host server), we reach `mongo` by giving `domain-name:port` to the `node-container`. This configuration works fine both locally (with/without Docker) and at the server, but only without Docker (so `npm start` "directly").

The Docker containers at the host are connected to a Docker `bridge` network.

We would like to use the `domain-name:port` configuration everywhere ideally, so that we don't have to think about the Docker side of things.

I would like to understand what happens in terms of networking. My rough networking understanding thinks this happens:

**WORKING SITUATION @ SERVER BY SKIPPING DOCKER**:

`Host[npm start]-->Node[need to check <domain-name:port>]-->DNS server[this is the IP you need]-->Host[Yes my IP + that port leads to mongo-container]`.

**BROKEN SITUATION @ SERVER BY USING NODE BEHIND DOCKER**:

`Host[docker-compose up etc... npm start via node container]-->Node[need to check <domain-name:port>]-->DNS server[Problem here?]`.

Thanks for any insights.

Comment: In the development setup, where is MongoDB running?  (What's `domain-name`?)  If you run it as-is under Docker, what do you get when trying to resolve `domain-name`?

Comment: @DavidMaze  MongoDB always runs at the "external server" (hosted by DigitalOcean), using a domain I own. So it's always i.e "mydomain.io:port".

Not sure I understood how to answer your last question. I googled resolving domains, and people suggest `getent hosts mydomain.io`.

Therefore I ran `getent hosts mydomain.io` three places:

1) Development setting; my local PC
2) At the DigitalOcean server,
3) At the DigitalOcean server attached to the "offending" node container using bash.

All produces the same result:

`<correct DigitalOcean server IP> <mydomain.io>`